# Redirect to previous page after login

Tags: login

I'm using [Profile Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/) to create login page. My login page is: example.com/login/.

I'm trying to redirect to previous page (the page user were before coming to example.com/login/). I have tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_previous_page', 10, 1);
function redirect_previous_page( $redirect_to ){
global $user;

$request = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

if ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'administrator') ) ) {

    return admin_url();

} elseif ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'subscriber') ) ) {

    return $request;
} 

return $redirect_to;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try `wp_get_referer()`.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not possible with this version of profile builder.